# unable to SSH into Mac OS X 10.11.6

Tags: macos, mac, ssh, macbook, osx-el-capitan

I'm running OS X El Capitan (10.11.6) and am trying to SSH into it from another machine (Windows 10) on the same LAN.

I can SSH into localhost from the OS X machine just fine. If I go to System Preferences -> Sharing -> Remote Login I see that Remote Login is on.

The IP address has changed since I originally enabled Remote Login. Maybe that has something to do with it?

I'm connecting by IP address using the IP address that `ifconfig` returned to me. The IP address is 192.168.1.123. I can SSH into 192.168.1.123 from 192.168.1.123 but I cannot do so from, say, 192.168.1.105.

It's as tho port 22 isn't open to external machines. With SSH, after you open up a TCP/IP connection there's the [protocol version exchange](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-4.2). The server and the client both send an identification string but I can't even get to that point because the TCP/IP connection is not even being established. I could post the Wiresharp pcap logs if that'd be helpful...

Comment: You gotta give us more to go on, like what the failure is like. Is there a message? Can you ping it? Are you connecting by name or by IP address? If by name, is it a name in a DNS server or is it just a .local name? Can you edit your question and paste in the output of `ssh -v …`?

Comment: @Spiff - I'm connecting by IP address using the IP address that `ifconfig` returned to me. The IP address is 192.168.1.123. I can SSH into 192.168.1.123 from 192.168.1.123 but I cannot do so from, say, 192.168.1.105. And I'm not trying to connect via OpenSSH - I'm trying to connect via PHP. And when I say I can't connect what I mean is I can't even open up a socket to 192.168.1.123:22.

Comment: idk how familiar you are with SSH but after you open up a TCP/IP connection there's the protocol version exchange (that's the terminology RFC4253 uses). The server and the client both send an identification string but I can't even get to that point because the TCP/IP connection is not even being established. I could post the Wiresharp pcap logs if that'd be helpful. It's like port 22 is completely closed on the machine except to local connections.

Comment: As for whether or not I can ping 192.168.1.123...  I cannot. But then again that doesn't surprise me. Windows, by default, doesn't even allow pings per https://kb.iu.edu/d/aopy . It wouldn't at all surprise me if Mac OS X didn't allow pings either..

Comment: I don't think El Capitan ships with the personal firewall on by default, but you can look and see if you've switched it on. It's in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall. If it's on, look in "Firewall Options…" to see if you've blocked SSH and pings (enabling "stealth mode" blocks pings).

Comment: If you turn the firewall completely off and still have the problem, please edit your question to include the output of "sudo netstat -naf inet | grep .22" as well as "sudo netstat -naf inet | grep .22". We need to see who, if anyone, is listening on port 22, and if they're binding to particular addresses or if they're using a wildcard.